# Is possible to create a shapefile with a specific encoding using ArcObjects?

Tags: shapefile, arcobjects, arcgis-engine

I have the code to create a shapefile programmatically, something like this [28310 - Create a new empty shapefile programmatically](https://geonet.esri.com/external-link.jspa?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupport.esri.com%2Ffr%2Fknowledgebase%2Ftecharticles%2Fdetail%2F28310)

moreover I am able to put the data from a layer in it.

It works perfectly.

Some client hands to me several layers that have data in Russian. When I export from my application to a shapefile I got the same behavior described here [esri - Character encoding support in geodatabases and shapefiles - Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange](https://geonet.esri.com/external-link.jspa?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgis.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F1461%2Fcharacter-encoding-support-in-geodatabases-and-shapefiles) .

the fields with Cyrillic alphabet appears like ???????? .

I found this article: [21106 - Read and write shapefile and dBASE files encoded in various code pages](https://geonet.esri.com/external-link.jspa?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupport.esri.com%2Fen%2Fknowledgebase%2Ftecharticles%2Fdetail%2F21106)  but it does not apply to ArcEngine (ArcObjects) .

Is there a way to change the encoding when I'm creating the shapefile using the workspace provided by the shapefileworkspacefactory?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the version of ArcEngine you have installed.